# Fabric dependency not working

Tags: android, maven, gradle, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to setup an Android project but can't make it build. Build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

At build I receive the error: Error:No cached version listing for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ available for offline mode.
If I uncheck Gradle offline mode I get the error: Error:White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

I tried changing https://maven.fabric.io/public to https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/ but its the same.

When I tried using http instead of https for the twitter sdk link in offline mode I got: Could not GET 'http://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project. And after enabling offline mode I got the error: No cached version listing for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ available for offline mode.

Comment: Try to use this url in the browser. Are you able to navigate?
 https://maven.fabric.io/public to https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io/

Comment: Yes, it is redirecting to twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io. That's the reason I've tried with twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/public/io. But I can't get pass those errors

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem, but after I refresh gradle setting, it disappeared.
1,in gradle setting,click some setting to other option
2,change back,click ok.then rebuild.maybe the problem is gone.